# How can I show data using Veiw.py file

Tags: python, django

Data enter in database, but does not showg on the Django website. The following error occurs in view.py file

```
File "C:\Users\usman\Downloads\OnlineCrime_ReportingSystem\firereport\views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .models import *
Import Error: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

To solve this error I tried a lot setting.py configuration urls.py. The error are not solved overall. The project is working accurate, but the data which is stored in database does not show on website.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you get errors when running your code, then your project is **not** working accurate. In any case, you have to provide a [mre].